# Unable to run ajax code in asp page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to run this piece of code in an ASPX page -

```
var username = ""*******";
var password = ""*******";
var vault = "*******";
var getToken = function (username , password , vault) {
// Request an encrypted token with the login information.
$.ajax ({
url: "http://example.org/REST/server/authenticationtokens.aspx",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType : "application /json",
data: JSON.stringify ({ Username: username , Password: password ,
VaultGuid: vault }),
success: processToken
});
};

var processToken = function (token) {
// Set the header.
$.ajaxSetup ({ headers: { "X- Authentication " : token.Value } });
};
```

But when I check the value of processToken I always get this

```
function (token) {// Set the header.$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { "X- Authentication ": token.Value} });
        };
```

Why is it not implementing? I know I have the URL and credentials correct.

Comment: Why is there spaces in your url?? `http :// example.org/REST/server/ authenticationtokens .aspx` this should be `http://example.org/REST/server/authenticationtokens.aspx`

Comment: When you say "check the value of processtoken", you are actually calling aren't you? A variable of type `function` will show the source code if you just display the variable and not call it :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You are right, I don't think I am checking for the value of processToken. How do I call the variable?

Comment: @Liam There are no spaces in the one I am executing, that was just a placeholder URL, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Manually you would do `processToken()`, but your ajax callback does that implicitely. You problem  is not `processToken`.

Comment: Add an `error: function(){alert("error")}` property to your Ajax call and see if it simply fails. You currently assume it works, but who knows? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I added the error peice and it is not failing. I'm a newbie at Ajax and some looking around tells me that I should not think sequential when it comes to AJAX. Right now I just want to see the value in processToken. When I do processToken();  in a seperate line I get a runtime error sayin "Unable to get property 'Value' of undefined or null refernce"  it breaks at this line $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { "X- Authentication ": token.Value} });

Comment: The `success` function is a callback that gets called long after you run the ajax line, so yes it is not sequential. Where are you trying to use the value? Your code, as formatted, it not very readable and appears incomplete. Can you tidy up your example a bit?

Comment: I need the processToken value for other API method calls I need to make (not displayed in the example). I have been able to accomplish the API calls via C# webmethods but didn't have any success via AJAX. I've decided to drop the question since I found an alternative solution. @TrueBlueAussie thank you for the guidance, someday I would like to understand how to read async replies.

Answer (score 0):

If your `dataType` is `json` you don't need to stringfy your data as well, just

```
data:{ Username: username , Password: password , VaultGuid: vault }
```

(i.e. pass an object) your likely encoding the json twice